# keep Scroll position with every refresh in grid view

Tags: android, gridview

I am refreshing the view style of items in grid view on click of some item in the action bar . What happens now is the view gets refreshed and the page is scrolled to the top position.

But i want that the on resetting the adapter my view should be updated but the scroll position should remain intact.

How do i do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can scroll your gridView to bottom with this code: (run it after the refresh..)

```
    private void scrollMygridViewToBottom() {
    gridView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Select the last row so it will scroll into view...
            gridView.setSelection(customGridAdapter.getCount() - 1);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but  want to scroll it back to the position where i clicked before resetting the grid view adapter .

Comment: I got the position form     onitemclicked and it worked, thanks